# Flex Starting tutorial?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to start developing with Flex3. Anyone can suggest some good free starting video tutorial/lecture and free online books available. its will be very helpful for me

Comment: I'd recommend you forget about Flex3 and start with Flex4.

Comment: Added a video series from Adobe, Flex in a Week.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is Peter De Haan's [Flex Examples Blog.](http://blog.flexexamples.com/flex-4-codename-gumbo/) Also start with Flex4.

There is also Adobe's [Flex in a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html) video tutorials.

Comment: ok.i am new with flex but can share some helping material for start Flex like(video tutorial,books) that are freely available.